# Debugging shiny - usage of trace() in case of reactives and observers

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to insert `browser()` function using `trace()` in shiny app. I know I could insert `browser()` manually, but I'm looking for the way to do this programmatically.

Here is my example:

```
library(shiny)
library(rlang)

ui <- fluidPage(
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  fun1 <- function() {
    a <- 1
  }
  
  fun2 <- reactive({
    b <- 2
  })
  
  observe({
    c <- 3
  })
  
  observe({
    trace(fun1, browser, where = env_parent(n = 2)) # it works
    fun1()
    #trace(fun2, browser, where = env_parent(n = 2)) # it doesn't work
    #fun2()
    #trace(observer_above, browser, where = env_parent(n = 2)) # no even idea how to refer
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I see it is possible for functions, but I can't do this in case of reactives and observers. Is it possible with `trace()` or `debug()`? If not, I'm also thinking about `body()`, but that's another story of course and I didn't tried it yet enough.

Comment: Have you looked at this https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/debugging.html ?

Comment: You are right! There is even paragraph `What about trace()?` However, to be honest, it is a little confusing since we have `it’s not possible to use this utility`, but then `functions at runtime that aren’t easily addressable`. I assume that if something wouldn't be possible because of adressable, then we would have `are not addressable`, not `are not easily addresable`. Thank you very much :) EDIT:we could even say that in this article they are saying about any function, but my example showed that one function was accessible by `trace()` even if this function wasn't defined before app started